# Check whether the R package keras has compiled a model

Tags: r, rstudio, keras

When I run the following R script I get summary information about a keras model and its added layers, but no confirmation that the model has been compiled. How do I check whether the compile step has been completed?

```
library(keras)

model <- keras_model_sequential()

model %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(20)) %>% 
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.5) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu') %>% 
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.5) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 10, activation = 'softmax') %>%
  compile(
    loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer = optimizer_sgd(lr = 0.01, decay = 1e-6, 
    momentum = 0.9, nesterov = TRUE),
    metrics = c('accuracy')     
    )

summary(model)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the built flag ?

```
library(keras)
model <- keras_model_sequential()

model$built # False

model %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(20)) %>% 
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.5) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu') %>% 
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.5) %>% 
  layer_activation(activation = 'relu') %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 10) %>% 
  layer_activation(activation = 'softmax')

model$built # False

model %>%
  compile(
    loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer = optimizer_sgd(lr = 0.01, decay = 1e-6, 
                          momentum = 0.9, nesterov = TRUE),
    metrics = c('accuracy')     
  )

model$built # True
```